# Are the Deis PostgreSQL and Redis installations available for App Usage?

Tags: deis

http://docs.deis.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/architecture/#architecture

PostgreSQL and Redis are used as part of the Deis architecture. My question is simple. Is it possible to use these for applications, or are they unavailable, or is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but generally speaking you want to keep your components away from your apps. I'd recommend staying away from giving users access to the database that all of Deis' data is being held on.